# LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in Overleaf

Tags: beamer, errors

I am using Overleaf to create a Beamer presentation. Here is my opening

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\mode<presentation>  
{  
  \usetheme{Luebeck}  
  \usecolortheme{beaver}  
  \usefonttheme{default}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]  
}   

\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}  

\title[3n+1]{The Collatz Conjecture}  
\author{James Bowman}  
\institute{MATH 295 Dr. First Last}  
\date{22 September 2016}  
\newtheorem{rmk}  
\begin{document}
```

I've seen on other sites that the issue comes from something before <\begin{document}>, but I can't find it.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide complete code we can try to compile which produces the error mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the inclusion of

```
\newtheorem{rmk}
```

Removing it and completing your code creates a minimal example which compiles.

Off-topic:

- better to say `american` than `english`, if that's what you mean;
- don't use `utf8x` if you can help it: use `utf8` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect usage of `\newtheorem`; you only supplied one mandatory argument, although it expects two (with possible optional arguments). Here is the complete specification:

```
\newtheorem*{<environment name>}[<numbered same as>]{<head text>}[<number within>]
```

with `*` being optional. You might be after

```
\newtheorem{rmk}{\translate{Remark}}
```

which will set a `Remark` with its own counter regime. Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Luebeck}
  \usecolortheme{beaver}
  \usefonttheme{default}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
  \setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]% Number theorem-related structures
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\title[3n+1]{The Collatz Conjecture}
\author{James Bowman}
\institute{MATH 295 Dr.\ First Last}
\date{\today}

\newtheorem{rmk}{\translate{Remark}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}

  \begin{rmk}
    This is a remark.
  \end{rmk}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```